# How to save & serialize an array, and then unserialize via PHP query?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I'm creating a new application that will be integrated with an external bot of sorts, and the bot will be accessing my site for specific information regarding new orders.  The application will work as follows:

1. Customer creates new order (order information is stored in database)
2. Customer is brought to a new page where they will complete a short form, and be presented with additional random information for their order.
3. Customer inserts, for example, their name into the input and submits the form.
4. The name and the additional information (this will be anywhere from 1 to 5 items that each have a corresponding amount) is saved into a new table.
5. The bot accesses the site and collects this information.
6. The bot performs it's tasks and responds back to the site to let it know that it's completed.

I currently have everything set, except I'm having a problem figuring out the best way to save, store and read the "additional information" when there are multiple. I figured the best way would be to collect the information into an array (in PHP), serialize it, save to table, and then when I query later for the bot to read, unserialize it.

This is the page where the bot will read the information:

```php
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT
   s.entity_id, s.increment_id, m.server_index, m.ign, mi.item_info,  m.timestamp, s.total_qty_ordered, m.bot_status
   FROM sales_flat_order as s
   INNER JOIN delivery_data as m ON s.entity_id = m.entity_id
   INNER JOIN delivery_item_data as mi ON m.entity_id = mi.entity_id
   WHERE s.store_id = "3" AND m.ready_status = "1" AND m.bot_status = 0'
 );
$stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

This issue is displaying the `item_info` in the result loop.

So for instance, the info being saved and serialized is:
`array(array(0,5000),array(1,4000))`

Serialized:
`a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:999999;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1999999;}}`

First, is this the best way?
Second, I'm having trouble unserializing it into a readable format with the rest of the desired information.

This is how the finished array would look:

```php
Array 
( 
   [0] => Array 
   ( 
      [entity_id] => 8333 

      [increment_id] => 300000028 

      [server_index] => 2 

      [ign] => TestName 

      [item_info] => Array 
                      (

                             [0] => 0

                             [1] => 5000
                      )
                     Array
                      (
                             [0] => 1
                             [1] => 4000
                      )

     [timestamp] => 2019-03-26 00:00:00 

     [total_qty_ordered] => 20.0000 

     [bot_status] => 0 

    ) 

 )
```

Comment: How do you expect it to look?

Comment: Added what I think it should look like to main post.

Comment: you can use jsonencode and jsondecode

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy so you’re saying to save it in the database as JSON? I didn’t think that was plausible unless you don’t plan on querying it, which I need to do

Comment: I'm also thinking that since storing arrays isn't really meant for a relational database, that if I were to store each additional item in it's own row, and have the primary key be the ID of the order, it could be more efficient.  However, if I did this, I would still need to ensure that each record that is queried is exactly 1 record. I can't have two listings with identical information (except for the additional info). More than one array for a single order would make it confusing.